# CSS Positioning Issue: When I stretch out my browser, the position of my picture will change

Tags: html, css

So when I fully reduce the browser size, I have my website looking like this, which is how I want it to look:

http://oi66.tinypic.com/10x7zw4.jpg

But when I start stretching out the browser, the position of my picture in the center will begin to change and move all the way to the left. I want the picture to stay on the center regardless of whether I stretch out the browser or reduce it. Is there a way I can fix this issue? Been trying to find out how to solve the issue but cannot find any clue. Please help, thank you.

My HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jason H Kang</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

  <div id="span">
      <h1 class="text-center">Jason H Kang</h1>

      <div class="intro">
          <p class="text-center">23 Years Old | Junior Web Developer | NJ</p>
      </div>

      <div class="hello">
          <p class="text-center">
          Hello I am Jason Kang. Welcome to my personal website!</br>Please feel free to contact me if you have further inquiries.</p>
      </div>
  </div>

    <div class="image">
     <img src="kangjason.jpg" alt="face" class="img-circle">
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="button">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Contact Me!</button>
    </div> -->

<div id="footer">
  <p class="copyright">Copyright: Jason Kang 2015</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #F8F8FF;
    color: #000000;
}


.navbar {
    background: rgba(114, 180, 39, 1)
}

.navbar .brand, .navbar .nav > li > a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 14em;
    padding-right: 0em;
    font-family: Gill Sans;
    font-size: 1.0em;
}
.navbar .brand, .navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}

#footer {
    background:#000000;
    width:100%;
    height:47px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.copyright {
    padding-top: 19px;
    padding-left: 1.3%;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: white;
}

.intro {
    padding-left: 0.35%;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}

.hello {
    padding-top: 1.5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}

.img-circle {
   width: 11.0em;
   height: 11.0em;
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin-left: 10em;
   margin-top: 1em;
   position: relative;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

To center a `block` level element, you use `margin:auto`:

```
.img-circle {
   width: 11.0em;
   height: 11.0em;
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin: auto;
   margin-top: 1em;
   position: relative;
   display:block;
  }
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jacobgray/v255amft/1/)
Or, alternatively, you can set the parent to `text-align:center;`:

```
.image {
  text-align: center;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jacobgray/ehqt0yhp/)

Comment: @InsomniacSabbir fixed, I just realized that the class was for the image, not the div

Answer (score 1):

Change your css for the img-circle class as follows

```
.img-circle {
    width: 11.0em;
    height: 11.0em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
 }
```